# Failed to map the path '/'. .net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have a .net app that I just opened on in visual studio 2010 and converted to 4.0 when it asked me on start-up. I go to try to build the site, and I get this error:

```
Failed to map the path '/'.

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

[InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/'.]
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +8804446
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath) +42
   System.Web.VirtualPath.MapPathInternal() +4
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) +107
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath) +37
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path) +99
   NU.WorkManagement.Lookup.Lookups..ctor() +82
   NU.WorkManagement.Engine.GlobalModule.Init(HttpApplication application) +624
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModulesCommon() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +43
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +828
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +327
```

I tried the most popular solution I found vis google (replace and ../ with ~/ but there wern't any...)

**Update:**

Lookups constructor:

```
public Lookups()
{           
    _dirPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + _xmlPath;           
}
```

Comment: Do you have a default document setup? Have you setup routes?

Comment: Can you post the constructor for the `Lookups` class? There's obviously something wrong being mapped. What web server are you running this on? Is this under a virtual directory? If you're running using the built in web server to VS, are you running VS as an administrator?

Comment: I am running using the built in web server to VS, yes i am running as admin. I firgured I would answer those two questions will I went to find the lookups class.

Comment: I don't know what a default document setup is, or routes...

Comment: Did you end up locating the source for the `Lookups` class?

Comment: Yes. I acutually had it referenced as a dll. I removed the dll and I no longer get this error (although I get some other errors, but thats a different issue). However, I'll post the code...

Comment: Is the current HttpContext what you're expecting?

Comment: @Will - I honestly have no idea, i didn't right the lookup component

Answer (score 49):

I know it's and old question, but for the record if you are running against IIS then

'iisreset' in the console may help resolving "Failed to map the path '/'." issue. I had this problem after renaming the sites in IIS.

Comment: Thank you! I just upgraded a .NET app and iisreset did the trick even though I had already tried restarting the site..

Comment: did not think this was going to help as i did reset the app pools but cheers, this totally resolved my issue too

Comment: Very nice! Same situation - Renamed a site and then started getting this issue. An iisreset fixed it immediately. Thanks :)

Comment: This solved it for me. You can also "Restart" or "Stop" and "Start" IIS from the IIS Server Manager. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 12):

I was just trying to go through an exercise in a Microsoft Step By Step book and I hit this problem when trying to precompile an ASP.NET appliction.

Here's how I got past this - and it took me a day to figure out!

When you open the Visual Studio Command Prompt to do your build/precompile, you must right-click and choose "Run As Administrator".

That's all it took for me when trying to run this aspnet_compiler -v DeployThis C:\DeployThis -f -u

Answer (score 5):

Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/")`. Notice the `~`.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem, IISRESET didn't do it. 
It turned out that the Virtual Directory we trying to map has a double backslash (`d:\folder\\subfolder\`) in the naming (IIS virtual directory was created with powershell script). Removing the extra backslash made HostingEnvironment.MapPath stop throwing exceptions.

Just in the case this could help somebody :-)